# Cast "1+2" string to integer value of 3 in PHP

Tags: php, casting

Is there a way to cast `"1+2"` string into integer value of `3`?

```
$a = "1+2";
echo (int)$a;            // 1
echo ( $a * 1 );         // 1
eval("\$a = \"$a\";");
echo $a;                 // "1+2"
```

I tried googling with no success.

Comment: Try to change `eval` to `intval`

Comment: The code you're evaluating would literally be `$a = "1+2";` Which is why you're just receiving the original.

Comment: @aldrin27 intval would be the same, just `1` :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a = "return " . $a . ";";
echo eval($a);
```

Comment: U R a life saver man. thanks